# How to make the li element in my project not move?

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox, absolute

I have a sidebar menu which has an indicator that shows the button which is selected.

The result I was expecting was that the indicator moved but the li elements wouldn't. But turns out they both move. I know the way I coded it is very unnecessary but I don't know how to do it otherwise. Can someone explain to me why the li elements move, how can I make my code more efficient and how to fix my problem?

```js
const menuButtonElements   = document.querySelectorAll('#menu-sdbr-list-item button');
const menuIndicatorElement = document.getElementById('menu-sdbr-list-indicator');
const menuSidebarUlElement = document.getElementById('menu-sdbr-list');
let selectedButtonIndex = 0;

menuButtonElements.forEach((value, index) => {
  value.addEventListener('click', () => {
    selectedButtonIndex = index;
    menuIndicatorElement.setAttribute('style', `
    margin-bottom: ${(index + 1) * -65}px;
    `)
    menuButtonElements.forEach(value => {
      value.setAttribute('style', `
      color: var(--color-surface-300);
      `)
    })
    menuButtonElements[index].setAttribute('style', `
    color: white;
    `)
  })
})
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Fira+Sans+Condensed:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap');
@import "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Material+Icons|Material+Icons+Outlined|Material+Icons+Round";
body {
  --color-primary-100: rgb(105, 54, 245);
  --color-primary-200: rgb(128, 78, 247);
  --color-primary-300: rgb(148, 100, 249);
  --color-primary-400: rgb(166, 122, 251);
  --color-primary-500: rgb(183, 144, 252);
  --color-primary-600: rgb(199, 165, 253);
  --color-surface-100: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  --color-surface-200: rgb(30, 30, 30);
  --color-surface-300: rgb(53, 53, 53);
  --color-surface-400: rgb(78, 78, 78);
  --color-surface-500: rgb(105, 105, 105);
  --color-surface-600: rgb(133, 133, 133);
  --color-surface-mixed-100: rgb(26, 22, 37);
  --color-surface-mixed-200: rgb(40, 35, 48);
  --color-surface-mixed-300: rgb(63, 58, 70);
  --color-surface-mixed-400: rgb(88, 83, 94);
  --color-surface-mixed-500: rgb(113, 109, 119);
  --color-surface-mixed-600: rgb(140, 136, 144);
  --color-primary-100-mix: 105, 54, 245;
  --color-primary-500-mix: 183, 144, 252;
  font-family: Fira Sans Condensed, Arial;
  margin: 0;
}

.menu-sidebar-overlay {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  z-index: 200;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  color: white;
}

.menu-sidebar {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 35vw;
  background-color: var(--color-primary-100);
  display: flex;
}

.menu-sidebar .rectangle {
  width: 15%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: var(--color-surface-300);
}

.menu-sdbr-title {
  display: inline;
  color: var(--color-primary-200);
  font-size: 40px;
  margin: 15px 0 0 10px;
  color: white;
}

.menu-sdbr-contents {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.menu-sdbr-list {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 90px 0 0 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 5px;
  flex: 1;
  height: 100%;
}

.menu-sdbr-list-indicator {
  margin-bottom: -65px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: var(--color-surface-300);
  z-index: 250;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  transition: margin-bottom 150ms;
}

.menu-sdbr-list-item button {
  position: relative;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 0 solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 15px;
  height: 60px;
  text-align: left;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  color: var(--color-surface-300);
  z-index: 300;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 400;
  z-index: 300;
  /*
border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
border-right: none;
*/
  transition: color 150ms;
}

.menu-sdbr-list-item button .material-icons {
  margin-right: 15px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="menu-sidebar-overlay">
  <div class="menu-sidebar">
    <div class="menu-sdbr-contents">
      <h1 class="menu-sdbr-title">MENU</h1>
      <ul class="menu-sdbr-list" id="menu-sdbr-list">
        <li class="menu-sdbr-list-indicator" id="menu-sdbr-list-indicator">
        </li>
        <li class="menu-sdbr-list-item" id="menu-sdbr-list-item">
          <button>
                  <span class="material-icons">dark_mode</span>
                  Dark Mode
                </button>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-sdbr-list-item" id="menu-sdbr-list-item">
          <button>
                  <span class="material-icons">settings</span>
                  Settings
                </button>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-sdbr-list-item" id="menu-sdbr-list-item">
          <button>
                  <span class="material-icons">logout</span>
                  Log Out
                </button>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="rectangle"></div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Having that `<div>` as a child of the `<ul>` element is invalid HTML.

Comment: @Pointy Oh I didn't know that, I'll update it real quick

Comment: To be more clear, the reason it's good to keep "honest" with HTML structure is that when you *don't*, you have to deal with how the browser decides to fix things up for you, which can sometimes result in strange things happening. In this case, browsers seem to tolerate bad `<ul>` structures, at least within reason, but I'd fix it anyway if I noticed it in code I cared about.

Comment: my bad, it is `<menu>` ->  [`<menu>` may replace a top `<ul>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/menu)

Comment: The negative `margin-bottom` you are setting for that indicator element, lets the following items "slide up". Remove the initial negative margin from the stylesheet, replace it with `position: relative`. And in your JS part, don't set `margin-bottom`, but `top` instead - but with a positive factor (i.e., multiply with 65, not -65)

Comment: And ideally this indicator would not be realized via an empty extra list item (semantically also rather bad), but via a pseudo child (`::before`) on the UL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than move an absolutely positioned element up and down, it would be easier to add and remove a class to the parent `li` and then add the background to that and highlight to the button based on the class.

This also has the added benefit of allowing you to add that class to one of the `li` if you want it pre-selected, in the example below, I have added it to the first `li`.

```js
const menuButtonElements = document.querySelectorAll('#menu-sdbr-list-item button');

// change the name of this foreach variable so you don't have matching var name inside the closure
menuButtonElements.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    // remove class from all button parent lis
    menuButtonElements.forEach(value => {
      value.parentNode.classList.remove('selected');
    });
    
    // add class to the clicked button parent li
    button.parentNode.classList.add('selected');
  })
})
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Fira+Sans+Condensed:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap');
@import "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Material+Icons|Material+Icons+Outlined|Material+Icons+Round";
body {
  --color-primary-100: rgb(105, 54, 245);
  --color-primary-200: rgb(128, 78, 247);
  --color-primary-300: rgb(148, 100, 249);
  --color-primary-400: rgb(166, 122, 251);
  --color-primary-500: rgb(183, 144, 252);
  --color-primary-600: rgb(199, 165, 253);
  --color-surface-100: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  --color-surface-200: rgb(30, 30, 30);
  --color-surface-300: rgb(53, 53, 53);
  --color-surface-400: rgb(78, 78, 78);
  --color-surface-500: rgb(105, 105, 105);
  --color-surface-600: rgb(133, 133, 133);
  --color-surface-mixed-100: rgb(26, 22, 37);
  --color-surface-mixed-200: rgb(40, 35, 48);
  --color-surface-mixed-300: rgb(63, 58, 70);
  --color-surface-mixed-400: rgb(88, 83, 94);
  --color-surface-mixed-500: rgb(113, 109, 119);
  --color-surface-mixed-600: rgb(140, 136, 144);
  --color-primary-100-mix: 105, 54, 245;
  --color-primary-500-mix: 183, 144, 252;
  font-family: Fira Sans Condensed, Arial;
  margin: 0;
}

.menu-sidebar-overlay {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  z-index: 200;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  color: white;
}

.menu-sidebar {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 35vw;
  background-color: var(--color-primary-100);
  display: flex;
}

.menu-sidebar .rectangle {
  width: 15%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: var(--color-surface-300);
}

.menu-sdbr-title {
  display: inline;
  color: var(--color-primary-200);
  font-size: 40px;
  margin: 15px 0 0 10px;
  color: white;
}

.menu-sdbr-contents {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.menu-sdbr-list {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 90px 0 0 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 5px;
  flex: 1;
  height: 100%;
}

.menu-sdbr-list-item button {
  position: relative;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 0 solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 15px;
  height: 60px;
  text-align: left;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  color: var(--color-surface-300);
  z-index: 300;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 400;
  z-index: 300;
  /*
border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
border-right: none;
*/
  transition: color 150ms;
}

.menu-sdbr-list-item button .material-icons {
  margin-right: 15px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

/* the below are the new classes for the selected item */
.menu-sdbr-list-item.selected {
  background-color: var(--color-surface-300);
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}

.menu-sdbr-list-item.selected button {
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<nav class="menu-sidebar-overlay">
  <div class="menu-sidebar">
    <div class="menu-sdbr-contents">
      <h1 class="menu-sdbr-title">MENU</h1>
      <ul class="menu-sdbr-list" id="menu-sdbr-list">
        <li class="menu-sdbr-list-item selected" id="menu-sdbr-list-item">
          <button>
                <span class="material-icons">dark_mode</span>
                Dark Mode
              </button>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-sdbr-list-item" id="menu-sdbr-list-item">
          <button>
                <span class="material-icons">settings</span>
                Settings
              </button>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-sdbr-list-item" id="menu-sdbr-list-item">
          <button>
                <span class="material-icons">logout</span>
                Log Out
              </button>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="rectangle"></div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Sorry, just realised you had an animation on your background for it to slide between the clicked elements - the above answer wouldn't do that, instead you would need to use absolute positioning to move the highlight without the rest of it moving:

```js
const menuButtonElements   = document.querySelectorAll('#menu-sdbr-list-item button');
const menuIndicatorElement = document.getElementById('menu-sdbr-list-indicator');
const menuSidebarUlElement = document.getElementById('menu-sdbr-list');
let selectedButtonIndex = 0;

const elementHeight = 65;
const initialPosition = -((menuButtonElements.length - 1) / 2) * elementHeight;

menuButtonElements.forEach((value, index) => {
  value.addEventListener('click', () => {
    selectedButtonIndex = index;
    menuIndicatorElement.setAttribute('style', `
    margin-top: ${initialPosition + (index * elementHeight)}px;
    `)
    menuButtonElements.forEach(value => {
      value.setAttribute('style', `
      color: var(--color-surface-300);
      `)
    })
    menuButtonElements[index].setAttribute('style', `
    color: white;
    `)
  })
})
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Fira+Sans+Condensed:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap');
@import "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Material+Icons|Material+Icons+Outlined|Material+Icons+Round";
body {
  --color-primary-100: rgb(105, 54, 245);
  --color-primary-200: rgb(128, 78, 247);
  --color-primary-300: rgb(148, 100, 249);
  --color-primary-400: rgb(166, 122, 251);
  --color-primary-500: rgb(183, 144, 252);
  --color-primary-600: rgb(199, 165, 253);
  --color-surface-100: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  --color-surface-200: rgb(30, 30, 30);
  --color-surface-300: rgb(53, 53, 53);
  --color-surface-400: rgb(78, 78, 78);
  --color-surface-500: rgb(105, 105, 105);
  --color-surface-600: rgb(133, 133, 133);
  --color-surface-mixed-100: rgb(26, 22, 37);
  --color-surface-mixed-200: rgb(40, 35, 48);
  --color-surface-mixed-300: rgb(63, 58, 70);
  --color-surface-mixed-400: rgb(88, 83, 94);
  --color-surface-mixed-500: rgb(113, 109, 119);
  --color-surface-mixed-600: rgb(140, 136, 144);
  --color-primary-100-mix: 105, 54, 245;
  --color-primary-500-mix: 183, 144, 252;
  font-family: Fira Sans Condensed, Arial;
  margin: 0;
}

.menu-sidebar-overlay {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  z-index: 200;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  color: white;
}

.menu-sidebar {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 35vw;
  background-color: var(--color-primary-100);
  display: flex;
}

.menu-sidebar .rectangle {
  width: 15%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: var(--color-surface-300);
}

.menu-sdbr-title {
  display: inline;
  color: var(--color-primary-200);
  font-size: 40px;
  margin: 15px 0 0 10px;
  color: white;
}

.menu-sdbr-contents {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.menu-sdbr-list {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 90px 0 0 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 5px;
  flex: 1;
  height: 100%;
}

.menu-sdbr-list-indicator {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -65px;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: var(--color-surface-300);
  z-index: 250;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  transition: margin-top 150ms;
}

.menu-sdbr-list-item button {
  position: relative;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 0 solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 15px;
  height: 60px;
  text-align: left;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  color: var(--color-surface-300);
  z-index: 300;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 400;
  z-index: 300;
  /*
border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
border-right: none;
*/
  transition: color 150ms;
}

.menu-sdbr-list-item button .material-icons {
  margin-right: 15px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="menu-sidebar-overlay">
  <div class="menu-sidebar">
    <div class="menu-sdbr-contents">
      <h1 class="menu-sdbr-title">MENU</h1>
      <ul class="menu-sdbr-list" id="menu-sdbr-list">
        <li class="menu-sdbr-list-indicator" id="menu-sdbr-list-indicator">
        </li>
        <li class="menu-sdbr-list-item" id="menu-sdbr-list-item">
          <button style="color: white">
                  <span class="material-icons">dark_mode</span>
                  Dark Mode
                </button>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-sdbr-list-item" id="menu-sdbr-list-item">
          <button>
                  <span class="material-icons">settings</span>
                  Settings
                </button>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-sdbr-list-item" id="menu-sdbr-list-item">
          <button>
                  <span class="material-icons">logout</span>
                  Log Out
                </button>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="rectangle"></div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

The initial `margin-top` is based on the number of elements above the middle element there is - as there are three elements and each element is 60px height with 5px gap, there is one element above therefore you margin -65px.  If there were 4 elements there would be 1.5 elements above so 1.5 * -65.

As you can see in the js, this is worked out using number of elements minus one then divided by 2 (gets the middle position), then the result is multiplied by the height

Comment: Wow. I understand the css part but I dont understand the initialPosition variable, if it's ok can you explain it to me?

Comment: the initial position is the calculation to get the margin top you use for the css - to get the middle position, it is number of elements minus 1 divided by 2, then you times that by the height - pretty much the same as the explanation for the css

Answer (score 1):

A bit hacky, but is this the kind of functionality you're looking for?

```js
const menuButtonElements   = document.querySelectorAll('#menu-sdbr-list-item button');
const menuIndicatorElement = document.getElementById('menu-sdbr-list-indicator');
const menuSidebarUlElement = document.getElementById('menu-sdbr-list');
let selectedButtonIndex = 0;
let marginTop = 27;

menuButtonElements.forEach((value, index) => {
  value.addEventListener('click', () => {
    menuIndicatorElement.style.display = "block";
    marginTop = (index - selectedButtonIndex) * 65 + marginTop;
    menuIndicatorElement.style.marginTop = marginTop + "px";
    menuButtonElements.forEach(value => {
      value.setAttribute('style', `
      color: var(--color-surface-300);
      `)
    })
    menuButtonElements[index].setAttribute('style', `
    color: white;
    `)
    selectedButtonIndex = index;
  })
})
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Fira+Sans+Condensed:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap');
@import "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Material+Icons|Material+Icons+Outlined|Material+Icons+Round";
body {
  --color-primary-100: rgb(105, 54, 245);
  --color-primary-200: rgb(128, 78, 247);
  --color-primary-300: rgb(148, 100, 249);
  --color-primary-400: rgb(166, 122, 251);
  --color-primary-500: rgb(183, 144, 252);
  --color-primary-600: rgb(199, 165, 253);
  --color-surface-100: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  --color-surface-200: rgb(30, 30, 30);
  --color-surface-300: rgb(53, 53, 53);
  --color-surface-400: rgb(78, 78, 78);
  --color-surface-500: rgb(105, 105, 105);
  --color-surface-600: rgb(133, 133, 133);
  --color-surface-mixed-100: rgb(26, 22, 37);
  --color-surface-mixed-200: rgb(40, 35, 48);
  --color-surface-mixed-300: rgb(63, 58, 70);
  --color-surface-mixed-400: rgb(88, 83, 94);
  --color-surface-mixed-500: rgb(113, 109, 119);
  --color-surface-mixed-600: rgb(140, 136, 144);
  --color-primary-100-mix: 105, 54, 245;
  --color-primary-500-mix: 183, 144, 252;
  font-family: Fira Sans Condensed, Arial;
  margin: 0;
}

.menu-sidebar-overlay {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  z-index: 200;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  color: white;
}

.menu-sidebar {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 35vw;
  background-color: var(--color-primary-100);
  display: flex;
}

.menu-sidebar .rectangle {
  width: 15%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: var(--color-surface-300);
}

.menu-sdbr-title {
  display: inline;
  color: var(--color-primary-200);
  font-size: 40px;
  margin: 15px 0 0 10px;
  color: white;
}

.menu-sdbr-contents {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.menu-sdbr-list {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 90px 0 0 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  gap: 5px;
  flex: 1;
  height: 100%;
}

.menu-sdbr-list-indicator {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: var(--color-surface-300);
  z-index: 250;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  transition: margin-top 150ms;
}

.menu-sdbr-list-item {
  width: 100%;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;  
}

.menu-sdbr-list-item button {
  position: relative;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 0 solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 15px;
  height: 60px;
  text-align: left;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  color: var(--color-surface-300);
  z-index: 300;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 400;
  z-index: 300;
  /*
border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
border-right: none;
*/
  transition: color 150ms;
}

.menu-sdbr-list-item button .material-icons {
  margin-right: 15px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="menu-sidebar-overlay">
  <div class="menu-sidebar">
    <div class="menu-sdbr-contents">
      <h1 class="menu-sdbr-title">MENU</h1>
        <div class="menu-sdbr-list-indicator" id="menu-sdbr-list-indicator">
        </div>
      <ul class="menu-sdbr-list" id="menu-sdbr-list">
        <li class="menu-sdbr-list-item" id="menu-sdbr-list-item">
          <button>
                  <span class="material-icons">dark_mode</span>
                  Dark Mode
                </button>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-sdbr-list-item" id="menu-sdbr-list-item">
          <button>
                  <span class="material-icons">settings</span>
                  Settings
                </button>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-sdbr-list-item" id="menu-sdbr-list-item">
          <button>
                  <span class="material-icons">logout</span>
                  Log Out
                </button>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="rectangle"></div>
  </div>
</nav>
```